# Load python object without tags

Tags: python, yaml

I want to load yaml document:

```yaml
a: 123
b: asd
```

to as a dataclass:

```py
@dataclass
class foo:
  a: int
  b: str
```

Unfortunately what I only can found is about adding the tags to the yaml file itself which is not an option.

**Can I force `pyyaml` to load specific class somehow?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dataclass-wizard`, which [uses `pyyaml`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/wizard_mixins.html#yamlwizard) behind the scenes to load a YAML string / file to a dataclass instance:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class Foo(YAMLWizard):
    a: int
    b: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from io import StringIO

    fp = StringIO("""
    a: '123'  # string value to test
    b: asd
    """)

    print(Foo.from_yaml(fp.read()))
```

Prints:

```
foo(a=123, b='asd')
```

*Disclaimer:* I am the creator and maintener of this library.

Comment: I see your class first loades the yaml "as is" and then uses the fromdict or fromlist methods form dataclasses utility library to load the object. This is not the case in my case.

Comment: this is correct, as far as I am aware. can you explain more about why you would like to load the yaml using tags in pyyaml?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976642/load-mapping-with-comlex-key