# Load mapping with complex keys

Tags: python, yaml

`pyyaml` fails to load the mappings with complex keys like bellow, because dict is not hashable.

```yaml
foo:
- {bar: test}: 123
```

Is it possible to force `pyyaml` to load mappings with complex keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, dictionary keys must be unique and hashable. A default dictionary is not hashable.

You need to create a custom hashable dictionary class. You can get inspiration from the answers here. [Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658/python-hashable-dicts)

After that, you need to tell pyyaml to use the custom dictionary. Maybe this question will lead you in the right direction.
[How to use custom dictionary class while loading yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629559/how-to-use-custom-dictionary-class-while-loading-yaml)

Answer (score 0):

I've "solved" this with following polyfill:

```py
from collections.abc import Hashable

from yaml import MappingNode
from yaml.constructor import BaseConstructor


def construct_mapping(self: BaseConstructor, node: MappingNode, deep=True):
    mapping = {}
    for key_node, value_node in node.value:
        key = self.construct_object(key_node, True)
        if not isinstance(key, Hashable):
            key = type('hashable', (key.__class__,), {'__hash__': lambda _: 1})(key)
        value = self.construct_object(value_node, True)
        mapping[key] = value
    return mapping


BaseConstructor.construct_mapping = construct_mapping
```